# dictionary or sub df from df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am totally new in programming in general, so please explain.
The general aim: I am dealing with x,y,z data. I want to reduce the number of points in each cell (could have variable sizes depinding on the project)to let's say 50 without affecting the mean value.
The problem: I have df with x,y,z,binnumber and I want to produce either dictionary(ex binnumber:[x,y,z],[x,y,z].....which is inside this bin), or some how sub datasets that I can work with as df so I can work with.
what I did:

```
    `# import the data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic_2d
inputpath=input("write the file path:")
Data = pd.read_csv(inputpath,  index_col=False, header= None, names =
['X','Y', 'Z'],skip_blank_lines=True) # file name , index =False means 
without index , names are the columns names
Data = pd.DataFrame(Data)

# creating the grid cells
min_x = int(min(Data['X'])) 
max_x = int(max(Data['X'])+1)
min_y = int(min(Data['Y']))
max_y = int(max(Data['Y'])+1)
bin_size = float(input('write the cell size:'))
bx= int(((max_x-min_x)//bin_size)+1) 
by=int(((max_y-min_y)//bin_size)+1)
xedges = np.linspace(min_x, max_x, bx, dtype=int) 
yedges = np.linspace(min_y, max_y, by, dtype=int) 

# assign the data to the cells
count, x_edge,y_edge,binnumber= binned_statistic_2d(Data['X'], Data['Y'], 
Data['Z'],bins=(xedges, yedges))
Data['binnumber']= binnumber
# sub sets
subsets = dict(Data.groupby('binnumber'))
print (subsets)
```

this did not work...
Another solution was to deal with the cells itself but it did not work also.

```
cells= {}
for i in xedges:
    for j in yedges:
        cells[str(i),str(j)]=[]
print(cells.keys())
for x in Data.X:
for y in Data.Y:
    for z in Data.Z:
        for k,v in cells.keys():
            if x>= int(k[0]) and x < int(k[0]) +1 and y>= int(k[1]) and y 
                 < int(k[1]) +1:
                k=(x,y,z)
            else:
                cells=('0')


print(cells)
```

Thanks for any try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import the data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic_2d

inputpath=input("write the file path:")
Data = pd.read_csv(inputpath,  index_col=False, header= None, names =
['X','Y', 'Z'],skip_blank_lines=True) # file name , index =False means 
without index , names are the columns names
Data = pd.DataFrame(Data)

# creating the grid cells
min_x = int(min(Data['X'])) 
max_x = int(max(Data['X'])+1)
min_y = int(min(Data['Y']))
max_y = int(max(Data['Y'])+1)
bin_size = float(input('write the cell size:'))
bx= int(((max_x-min_x)//bin_size)+1) 
by=int(((max_y-min_y)//bin_size)+1)
xedges = np.linspace(min_x, max_x, bx, dtype=int) 
yedges = np.linspace(min_y, max_y, by, dtype=int) 

# assign the data to the cells
count, x_edge,y_edge,binnumber= binned_statistic_2d(Data['X'], Data['Y'], 
Data['Z'],bins=(xedges, yedges))
Data['binnumber']= binnumber

# making dictionary with >>> binnumber: all associated points......
Data['value'] = list(zip(Data['X'], Data['Y'], Data['Z']))
d = defaultdict(list)
for idx, row in Data.iterrows():
    d[row['binnumber']].append(row['value'])
```